# Query to get properties of quantity for a certain entity class

Tags: sparql, wikidata

What I am trying to do is to get properties with quantity property types of a certain class (such as City, Country, Human, River, Region, Mountain, etc). I tried several classes like Country (`wd:Q6256`) works okay with the query below, but many other classes makes the query to exeed time limit. How can I achieve the result optimizing the query below? or is there any other way to get the properties of Quantity type in a certain class?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p_ ?pLabel ?pAltLabel
WHERE {
  VALUES (?class) {(wd:Q515)}
  ?x ?p_ [].
  ?x p:P31/ps:P31 ?class.

  ?p wikibase:claim ?p_.
  ?p wikibase:directClaim ?pwdt.
  ?p wikibase:propertyType ?pType.
  FILTER (?pType = wikibase:Quantity)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ko,en". }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Attempt 1: Optimizing the query

Some observations:

- Instead of `p:P31/ps:P31`, you could use `wdt:P31` which is faster by avoiding the two-property hop, but finds only the [truthy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements) statements
- The expensive part is the call to the label service at the end, as can be seen by commenting that line out by placing `#` at the start of the line
- The query retrieves every claim on every city (many!), gets the properties of the claims (few!), and only removes the duplicates in the end (with `DISTINCT`)
- As a result, the label service is called many times for the same property, once per claim! This is the big problem with the query
- This can be avoided by moving the retrieval of properties with the `DISTINCT` into a subquery, and calling the label service only at the end on the few properties
- After that change it should be fast, but is still slow because the query optimiser seems to evaluate the query in the wrong order. Following hints from [this page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/query_optimization), we can turn the query optimiser off.

This works for me:

```
SELECT ?p ?pLabel ?pAltLabel {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?p_ {
      VALUES ?class { wd:Q515 }
      ?x wdt:P31 ?class.
      ?x ?p_ [].
    }
  }
  ?p wikibase:claim ?p_.
  ?p wikibase:propertyType ?pType.
  FILTER (?pType = wikibase:Quantity)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

### Attempt 2: Splitting the task into multiple queries

Having learned that the approach above doesn't work for some of the biggest categories (like `wd:Q5`, “human”), I tried a different approach. This will get all results, but not in a single query. It requires sending ~25 individual queries and combining the results afterwards:

- We start by listing the quantity properties. There are, as of today, 503 of them.
- We want to keep only those properties that are actually used on an item of type “human”.
- Because that check is so slow (it needs to look at millions of items), we start by only checking the first 20 properties from our list.
- In the second query, we're going to check the next 20, and so on.

This is the query that tests the first 20 properties:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p ?pLabel ?pAltLabel {
  hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .
  {
    SELECT ?p ?pLabel ?pAltLabel {
      ?p wikibase:propertyType wikibase:Quantity.
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
    }
    OFFSET 0 LIMIT 20
  }
  ?p wikibase:claim ?p_.
  ?x ?p_ [].
  ?x wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
}
```

Increase the `OFFSET` to 20, 40, 60 and so on, up to 500, to test all properties.

Comment: Nice answer. Just a comment, the path `p:31/ps:31` was suggest in one of his [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55314201/my-sparql-only-get-answers-partially-missing-some-answers-unanswered) and has to be used to get all statements not only the [truthy](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Truthy_statements) type statements. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47100906/4744359

Comment: @AKSW thanks, that is good to know, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @cygri Thank you very much. It is very good to know. I didn't recognize the way before. It works for me too. However, it works for ```wd:Q515``` but still time out with ```wd:Q5```(human) so I need to optimse   the query further. Anyway it was much help.

Comment: @KeanuPaik I suppose there's lots of humans in Wikidata! I get a result for Q5 by adding `LIMIT 4000` after the inner `SELECT`; with `LIMIT 5000` it times out. That will return only partial results so it will miss some properties. I'm afraid that's the best I can do!

Comment: @KeanuPaik Actually I gave it another go, and have updated the answer with a different approach that splits the task into multiple queries. Maybe that's acceptable?

Comment: @cygri Oh, it is great. Actually I also tried with ```LIMIT``` in the query as well. But second approach can get all the properties. Totally different approach and good alternative. Thank you for your great help.